# filtering MATLAB results with strfind

Tags: matlab

```
myver = ver;
myver(1:5).Name
```

returns:

```
ans = 'Computer Vision System Toolbox'
ans = 'Control System Toolbox'
ans = 'Curve Fitting Toolbox'
ans = 'DSP System Toolbox'
ans = 'Database Toolbox'
```

Stringfind

```
strfind(myver(1:35).Name,'Toolbox')
```

Returns the error:

```
Error using strfind
Unrecognized parameter name 'Curve Fitting Toolbox'.
```

I am seeking a list of all entries with the word 'Toolbox'.  Why does strfind err on the third entry?

Any feedback or edits that sharpen the question are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`myver(1:5).Name` returns a [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html).

`strfind(myver(1:5).Name,'Toolbox')`  is the same as:

```matlab
strfind('Computer Vision System Toolbox', 'Control System Toolbox', ...
 'Curve Fitting Toolbox', 'DSP System Toolbox', 'Database Toolbox', 'Toolbox');
```

Clearly this is invalid syntax. Read the documentation of the [`strfind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) function to see the valid syntax.

You need to combine this comma-separated list's elements in a cell-array before applying `strfind` i.e:

```matlab
tmpVar = {myver(1:35).Name};        %concatenating the list into a cell-array
check = strfind(tmpVar,'Toolbox');  %finding which cells contain 'Toolbox'
logidx = ~cellfun(@isempty,check);  %logical indices of the cells which contain 'Toolbox'
tmpVar{logidx}                      %Required result (as a comma-separated list)
```